# Adding to an array from a separate class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have made a listView that is populated with an array. I can add data to this listview by entering in data in a textbox called `txtinputs` and then click a button called `btnAdds` this all works fine when I have it all in a single class. However what I want to do is have this on 2 separate screens using 2 separate classes, the `txtinputs` and the `btnAdds` in a separate class than the listView. When the data is entered into the `txtinputs` and the `btnAdds` is selected it will add that data into the listView on a seperate class. I want the listView in a class called ListDeadlines and my textBox and Button in a class called AddDeadline. 
I currently add the data into the listView like this.

```
public ArrayList<String> arrayList;
public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
public EditText txtInput;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_deadlines);
    final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listv);
    String[] items= {"HCI","ITM","Presentation"};
    arrayList=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.txtitem,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    txtInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtinputs);
    Button btAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdds);
    btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            String newItem=txtInput.getText().toString();
            arrayList.add(newItem);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();;


        }
    });

}
```

I have tried to do it like this in my `AddDeadline` class like this however I get a runtime on the button click

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_deadline);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   final ListDeadlines lst= new ListDeadlines();
    lst.txtInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtinput);
    Button btAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newItem = lst.txtInput.getText().toString();
            lst.arrayList.add(newItem);
            lst.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
}
```

I want to achieve something like this[image]

Comment: After adding item, do you want to close your second activity and go back to first one? Use startActivityForResult and pass your data in an intent.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to do @GokhanArik I'm new with android development, if you don't mind is there anyways you could show me how I could go about doing this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ListDeadLinesActivity` when a user hit the "+" button you want to start `AddDeadlineActivity` for a result.

You can put this code inside the `onClick` of that "+" button.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddDeadlineActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_DEADLINE_REQUEST);
```

`ADD_DEADLINE_REQUEST` is the request code, you can declare a static int.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result", yourEditText.getText().toString());

            setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

In your `ListDeadLinesActivity` override `onActivityResult` method,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == ADD_DEADLINE_REQUEST){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String item = data.getStringExtra("result");
            arrayList.add(item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

[Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: I will give that a shot and get back to you thanks :)

Comment: Where would I enter that second section of code? Would I just enter it under my             `@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                String newItem=txtInput.getText().toString();
                arrayList.add(newItem);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });`

Comment: You legend it worked like a dream. Thanks so much. If you up-vote my question I can up-vote your answer as I don't have enough reputation at the moment. Thanks again.

Comment: You need to learn which answer to accept first. The guy above me just copied the answer from my code and you accepted his answer?